# Temporal scrolling disabling in Android Scroll View

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

*usual excuse that I'm a beginner *

I created an Activity in Android Studio with a vertical scroll view and added several items, including a webview to it.

This works fine, I can scroll up and down and the web view is displayed properly.

My problem is, that the object displayed in the webview is a map(leaflet.js) having it's own horizontal and vertical scrolling as soon as I move my finger.

Now when I move my finger above or below the webview horizontal nothing happens and if I move them on top of the webview the map scrolls left and right, but unfortunately whenever I move my finger vertical the scroll view moves up and down and the webview stays in exactly the same vertical position.

Is it possible to disable the vertical scrolling of the scroll view as long as my finger is touching the map? This is my not working code:

```
ScrollView scv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                scv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                scv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

            }
            return true;
        };

    });
```

After adding this code even horizontal scrolling is not possible anymore, but maybe you can help me make it work.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend ScrollView as follows to disable scrolling

```
class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

   // true if we can scroll (not locked)
   // false if we cannot scroll (locked)
   private boolean mScrollable = true;

   public View.OnTouchListener unsuportedTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
               mScrollable = false;
           }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
               mScrollable = true;
           }
           return false;
       }
    }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
               // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
               return mScrollable && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
       }else{
               return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
       // we are not scrollable
       return mScrollable && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
   }

}
```

in your XML file (just changed the ScrollView to your special LockableScrollView):

```
<com.your.package.LockableScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/QuranGalleryScrollView" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


</com.mypackagename.LockableScrollView>
```

enabling/disabling scroll view:

```
LockableScrollView scv = (LockableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.QuranGalleryScrollView);
myWebView.setOnTouchListener(scv.unsuportedTouchListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick support, worked perfect the way I wanted it :)

Comment: this solution don't allow to inside objects ( like RV ) to operate